# The adjective "dashing": can it be used to describe a woman?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, present-participles

Can you say of a woman that she is "dashing", meaning that she looks stupendous, graceful etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search of [Google books](http://www.google.com/search?q=dashing%20woman&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) shows that "dashing woman" has been used before, and FumbleFingers kindly did this [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=dashing%20young%20man,dashing%20young%20woman&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) comparing the use of "dashing" with relation to men and women, showing that it is much more common to use dashing for men.

Etymology Online gives the origin of ["dashing"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dashing&searchmode=none) as "cutting a dash", meaning acting brilliantly, from "dash" in the sense of showy appearance.  Indeed, [Dictionary.Com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dashing) demonstrates that the idiomatic use of "dashing" as "make a striking appearance" is still common usage.

So yes, I think a woman should like to be described as dashing.  Although you might use "[fetching](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fetching)" if you think she wouldn't slap you.  As this [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=fetching%20young%20woman,dashing%20young%20woman&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) demonstrates, "fetching" is a bit more common these days.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll try my luck tonight actually with that adjective, see how that goes for the lady... I'm French, her British, so there's that :)

Comment: @Guy Fawkes If British women are like American women: if you're French, you can probably use whatever word you want and she'll swoon. Good luck :)

Comment: @Kit You were right :)

Answer (score 2):

**Dashing** means 'energetic, spirited, showy, stylish' and can be used to describe a woman.

However, it would not describe a woman as "graceful", or "beautiful", or "gentle", but rather more of the "charming", "bright", "lively" description.